# datos basura en resultado de matriz

Tags: c++, codeblocks

me podrían ayudar a quitar todos esos datos basura, nose como se podria hacer en c++

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo para que lo prueben

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;



void hojaPrestamoCalculo(int,int);


void hojaPrestamoCalculo(int prestamo,int plazoj){
        int plazo = 6;

        int prueba[3][2]={{'\0'}};

        double j=prestamo;
        for(int i = 0; i < plazo; i++){

            prueba[i][0] = 1;
            prueba[i][1] = 2;
            prueba[i][3] = 3;


        }
            cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
            cout<<"        | Cuota |        | Amortizacion |       | Saldo |                   \n";
            cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
        for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
            cout<<"Mes :"<<i+1<<"  "<<prueba[i][0]<<"        "<<prueba[i][1]<<"        "<<prueba[i][2]<<endl;
        }


        system("pause");

}




int main()
{

    hojaPrestamoCalculo(1000000, 6);

}
```

por mas que lo intento la columna 3 deberia estar llena de solo valores 3, pero los datos basura me los quitan

si la matriz le imprimo las 3 filas igual los datos basura me duplican los 1 y me los pasan a la columna 2 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: aun asi no funciona

Comment: ocupo que la matriz me muestre en cada  columna un numero como al ingresarlos

Comment: porque dices que son 2 columnas, no son 3 ? porque comienza de 0,1,2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes algunos errores:

- La matriz es de 3 filas pero imprimes más.
- El parámetro `plazoj` es totalmente ignorado y se usa la variable `plazo` que ocupa más filas de la matriz.
- Imprimes la columna 3 de la matriz mientras que solo tiene 2 columnas.

  `prueba[3][2]` es una matriz de 3 filas por 2 columnas. O mejor dicho: es un arreglo de 3 arreglos de 2 elementos. La posicion `[i][2]` y `[i][3]` no son válidas.

En todo caso, podría ser así:

```
void hojaPrestamoCalculo(int prestamo) {   
    int prueba[15][3] = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
        prueba[i][0] = 1;
        prueba[i][1] = 2;
        prueba[i][2] = 3;
    }

    ...

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
        cout<<"Mes :"<<i+1<<"  "<<prueba[i][0]<<"        "<<prueba[i][1]<<"        "<<prueba[i][2]<<endl;
    }
}
```